# How should a method of a category of NSMutableArray delete several items from itself?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a category of NSMutableArray which has a deletion method:

```
@interface NSMutableArray(MyCategory)
- (void) deleteItemsMatchingCriteria: (SomeCriteria) theCriteria;
@end
```

How should this be implemented?

To iterate through arrays I usually use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: but of course one cannot delete an item from the array while in the middle of the iteration.

Is there a canonical way of doing this for arrays in general, and does it differ if the method doing the deletion is a category of the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` method:

```
[self removeObjectsAtIndexes:[self indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:
    ^BOOL (id element, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop) {
        return /* YES if the object needs to be removed */;
    }]
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Obviously in the code below where i check for theCriteria you'll have more logic to determine if the object should be removed.

```
-(void)deleteItemsMatchingCriteria:(BOOL)theCriteria{
    NSMutableIndexSet *remove = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];

    [self enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if(theCriteria){
            [remove addIndex:idx];
        }
    }];

    [self removeObjectsAtIndexes:remove];
}
```